# Needing more efficient grep for excluding numerical value when in a string

Tags: log, grep

I am grepping log files looking for results that show the output of 'queued 10' or higher.

Ex.
`grep 'queued' *20231016* | grep -vE 'queued 1|queued 2|queued 3'`

This works fine, however, is there a more efficient way to grep this if I would like to see anything where the numerical value after queued is greater than 10,20, etc...?  It obviously isn't feasible to pipe that many exclusions past what is shown above.

Answer (score 1):

While you *could* construct a regular expression to match a numeric range, I'd suggest switching to a tool that can perform numeric comparisons directly. For example

```
perl -ne 'print if /queued (\d+)/ && $1 > 10'
```

or

```
gawk 'match($0,/queued ([[:digit:]]+)/,a) && a[1] > 10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually looking for "queued" followed by 2 or more digits. It's easy:

```
grep -E 'queued [1-9][0-9]+' *20231016*
```

Always remember that regular expressions deal with text *patterns*, rather than data *values*.